# EF Core: How can I register multiple value conversions?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

The following are valid ways to register value conversions (snippets taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Rider>()
        .Property(e => e.Mount)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => (EquineBeast)Enum.Parse(typeof(EquineBeast), v));
}
```

and

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var converter = new ValueConverter<EquineBeast, string>(
        v => v.ToString(),
        v => (EquineBeast)Enum.Parse(typeof(EquineBeast), v));

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Rider>()
        .Property(e => e.SecondaryMount)
        .HasConversion(converter);
}
```

My Question:

- If I'd like to register multiple value conversions on the same type (just like the snippets above) how can I accomplish that in the same line?

For example, I'd expect the following to work, but it **doesn't**.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var converter = new ValueConverter<EquineBeast, string>(
        v => v.ToString(),
        v => (EquineBeast)Enum.Parse(typeof(EquineBeast), v));

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Rider>()
        .Property(e => e.Mount)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => (EquineBeast)Enum.Parse(typeof(EquineBeast), v))
        .Property(e => e.SecondaryMount) // doesn't work; can't append another property registration
        .HasConversion(converter);
}
```

Comment: Well just suck it up and register them all separately on an entity level

Comment: I believe they must be in multiple statements.

Comment: related: [Mechanism/API to specify a default conversion for any property of a given type in the model](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10784)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure each property is one statement, such as the below.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var converter = new ValueConverter<EquineBeast, string>(
        v => v.ToString(),
        v => (EquineBeast)Enum.Parse(typeof(EquineBeast), v));

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Rider>()
        .Property(e => e.Mount)
        .HasConversion(converter);
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Rider>()
        .Property(e => e.SecondaryMount)
        .HasConversion(converter);

}
```